# flex 2.3.1 Simpleinfowinwidget deprecation

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-viewer

I have been using the simpleinfopopup widget and recently read that it is being deprecated with 2.3.1.
1. What are the positives and negatives of the popup you are using in flex?
I also have been trying to implement the link_field without success in this popup.
2. Have you had any success getting a url link in your popups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/28414-Hyperlinks-using-the-Simple-Info-Widget) from the ESRI forums to be quite helpful in deciding what to use as an alternative. They give many different alternatives to the SimpleInfoWidget. They also cover your two questions better than I could by myself.

Link:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/28414-Hyperlinks-using-the-Simple-Info-Widget

Comment: just what I have been looking for. I just discovered yesterday that even though I downloaded... I didn't ever install 2.3. I think I'll load it and see if the siw has changed in it prior to following the other widget options.